# Firebase Missing dSYM files

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

Firebase Missing dSYM files

I Followed the instruction to upload dSYM file
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
-gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs

I ran it in run script and directly run in terminal it shows Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols but it repeatedly shows missing dSYM

myapp pod folder path /FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
-gsp / myapp google plist path /GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /dSYMs file path

Comment: If you have missing dSYMs, you have to upload the dSYMs for that prior build (if you still have them). (Uploading new dSYMs won’t fix the missing dSYMs for prior builds.) If your missing dSYMs are for some build previously uploaded to TestFlight, you can go to AppStoreConnect and download those prior dSYMs and then use `upload-symbols` for them.

Comment: So, is the problem that you have some old builds with missing dSYMs or that you’re unable to upload new dSYMs? If the latter, please share the console output of your dSYM upload.

Comment: console output  "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols " after I upload  dSYMs

Comment: So, it sounds like you must have some build in the past for which you neglected to upload the dSYMs. Find the dSYMs for that build, assuming you have them at all, and upload them.

Comment: Have you tried locating your dSYMs following this guide? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#locate